# How do I link arrays from different buttons together?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm new to java and I require some assistance!

After working on my code for a long time I finally found the problem to my code. The problem is that I have 3 seperate buttons that are private void, if that has to do with anything, and each button is suppose to add/subtract strings from my array. I have an array called strArray and 3 buttons that are suppose to modify it when clicked, Initialize, Add, and Remove. The first button is Initialize which when clicked outputs

```
private void togbtnInitializeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    togbtnAdd.setEnabled(true);
    togbtnRemove.setEnabled(true);
    togbtnDisplay.setEnabled(true);

    String[] strArray = {"Calvin Harris - Overdrive(Part 2)", "DVBBS & Borgeous - TSUNAMI", "Martin Garrix - Tremor", "Martin Garrix - Animals", "Firebeatz - Max Ammo"};
    int intArrayLength = strArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < intArrayLength; i++){
        this.txtAreaOutput.setText(txtAreaOutput.getText() + "\n" + strArray[i]);
    }
    togbtnInitialize.setEnabled(false);        
}
```

into a textArea in my gui. So now that I have this outputted, the Initialize button is disabled and Add and Remove is enabled. This is where I found the problem. After I type in a string and click the add button, it didn't add the string into the strArray I typed in the Initialize button code. I checked this by printing strArray using the "add" button and it only held the one that I just added into it.

```
private void togbtnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    strArray.add(this.txtInputName.getText());
    System.out.println(strArray);
    this.txtAreaOutput.setText(txtAreaOutput.getText() + "\n" + strArray.get(strArray.size()));        
}
```

How can I link all of the strArrays together so that if I do something to it with one button, it also changes the strArray in the other button? Thanks in advance!

Edit:I'm still not able to access strArray unless make a variable for it in my buttons.

public class U3A4_CDCollection extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public U3A4_CDCollection() {
    initComponents();
    ArrayList<String> strArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    strArray.add("Calvin Harris - Overdrive(Part 2)");
    strArray.add("DVBBS & Borgeous - TSUNAMI");
    strArray.add("Martin Garrix - Tremor");
    strArray.add("Martin Garrix - Animals");
    strArray.add("Firebeatz - Max Ammo");
}
```

Comment: Make `strArray` an instance field so that each of the buttons can access it.  It would be better to encapsalte it within some kind of model, but this would be a start...

Comment: sorry could you explain how I can do that or give me a link on where I could learn?

Comment: [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: What is strArray? There are two - one is of type array `String[] strArray` and on other you're calling add method  `strArray.add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much context missing, not to mention the confusion of the use of an array and something else which has a `add` method...

Essentially, if you want the methods of your class to be able to interact with the same variable, that variable should be declared as a class instance field.  See [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details.

```
public class U3A4_CDCollection extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private ArrayList<String> strArray;

    public U3A4_CDCollection() {
        initComponents();
        strArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        strArray.add("Calvin Harris - Overdrive(Part 2)");
        strArray.add("DVBBS & Borgeous - TSUNAMI");
        strArray.add("Martin Garrix - Tremor");
        strArray.add("Martin Garrix - Animals");
        strArray.add("Firebeatz - Max Ammo");

}
```